# How to set size and various attributes for all grids in GridPane in Scenebuilder/JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, scenebuilder

**NOTE:** This is not homework. My Swing application was homework, but it's already completed. I'm doing this for my own knowledge to get a better understanding of JavaFX and Scenebuilder.

I created a Swing application that contained a 27x27 grid. Upon clicking "Normal Setup", only the center square is visible.

[image: Swing GUI Initialization]

I am attemtping to translate everything into JavaFx, and I am using Scenebuilder. I'm still learning how to use this, and I'm unsure if I have my GridPane placed correctly (Notice how creating a 27 x 27 grid makes it go beyond the bounds of the parent). I can work on that later.

[image: JavaFX GridNode with Scenebuilder]

What I would like to know is if you can set all of the attributes for each node across the board. I had to go into my FXML file and manually change each node size in the 27x27 grid. This will get exhausting eventually. Surely there is a way to do this? 
As you can see each node will have a Label template, and it will only be visible when a certain ant accesses it.

In my Swing version, an example of setting everything for all nodes looks like so:

```
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ColonyView.NODE_SIZE, ColonyView.NODE_SIZE));
```

where the "NODE_SIZE" is:

```
    public final static int NODE_SIZE = 96
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a node in your `GridPane` and press STRG + A

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: I may end up not using Scenebuilder, however. I have a class "ColonyNodeView" that extends JPanel. I'm basically creating a 27 x 27 grid of JPanels that will have Labels (when visible), and the yellow color you see to match the background. I just need to figure out how to define these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to set the yellow background. See https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html for details.